# How to insert column name in the destination table in ssis?

Tags: excel, ssis, header

reference to question[image: 1]

As shown in the image... I have an excel sheet, which contains 32 tables one after the other (I have taken 2 tables in the image) may grow the table count... but the metadata is same for all the tables.Table has two columns one is constant(Name) & another one will get change(TPA,TPB.. etc) but there is no change in the column position.
now the problem is how to hold the header and inserted as a T_type value into the destination table ?

the no of rows in each table is not fixed( so we can't go for cell reference).

Answer (score 2):

### The problem as I understand it

I believe you have data in Excel that looks approximately

```
Name | TPA
abc  | x
...

Name | TPB
acz  | p
```

The data could be described as blocks of data. A block is defined bounded by a starting row with the value of `Name` in it. The next cell on that row will contain a value that applies to all subsequent rows.

After the header row, you will need to pull out the key value pairs and write them plus the table name into your destination.

The meta data remains consistent, it's just the source data is all banjaxed.

### Resolution

This is exactly the problem I had to overcome when I wrote [SSIS Excel Source via SSIS](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/04/ssis-excel-source-via-script.html). We had to source our data feeds from reports instead of clean tabular data. Using that approach, you would simply define your equivalent `ParseSample` method and there in the foreach loop (line 71 of ExcelParser) you'd put in the logic of a block is everything from a field with a value of 'Name' until you encounter an empty row.

Psuedocode approximate

```
# enumerate through all my source data
foreach row in source data
    # assign values to local variables
    col0 = row[0]
    col1 = row[1] 

    # Test for end of block
    if col0 == "Name"
        tableName = col1
    else if col0 == string.Empty
        # do nothing
    else
        newRow = dataTable.NewRow()
        newRow[0] = col0
        newRow[1] = tableName
        newRow[2] = col1
        dataTable.Add(newRow)
```

If you want to simplify the matter, you can have all the parsing logic in the ScriptMain and dispense with all the data table nonsense.

Upside is there'd be less code, downside is that debugging scripts is the devil in SSIS pre-2012. It's still kludgey in 2012 but it's better than the nothing that came before it.

Comment: Can we achieve this without using script component ?

Comment: You can use an Excel Source and it'll treat all the inbound data as unicode, which is fine. The challenge not using script component is that you have windows of data. The first row of your window has the target table name, subsequent rows need to use that name. There isn't really an OOB mechanism in SSIS to allow you to apply a previous row's value to the current row. An alternative approach would still require a script component except instead of being the Source, it'd generate surrogate keys to allow subsequent rows to be grouped. Write all of that to a staging table and then use SQL